# It's possible to use requests in ironpython 2.7.5?

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-requests, ironpython

I've successful installed pip on ironpython. But when i try to install requests with "ipy.exe -X:Frames -m pip install requests" in a administrator console I get the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py run on 02/02/16 16:13:53
Downloading/unpacking html5lib
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/html5lib/
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\panta\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_panta...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1183, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 566, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 670, in get_page
    resp = session.get(url, headers={"Accept": "text/html"})
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 317, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(conn, method, url,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 291, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 955, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 989, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\httplib.py", line 773, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 197, in connect
    match_hostname(self.sock.getpeercert(),
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\ssl_match_hostname\_implementation.py", line 88, in match_hostname
    for key, value in sub:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So, there is some way to install requests on ironpython now that supports pip? I tried using (in administrator console):

- ipy.exe -X:Frames -m pip install requests
- ipy.exe -X:FullFrames -m pip install requests
- ipy.exe -m pip install requests
- ipy.exe -X:Frames Scripts\pip2.7.exe install requests
- ipy.exe -X:FullFrames Scripts\pip2.7.exe install requests
- ipy.exe -X:FullFrames Scripts\pip2.exe install requests
- ipy.exe -X:FullFrames Scripts\easy_install-2.7.exe requests

An when i try "ipy.exe -X:FullFrames -m easy_install requests" i get:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\weakref.py:1: DeprecationWarning: object.__init__() takes no parameters for type KeyedRef
  """Weak reference support for Python.
Searching for requests
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/
Best match: requests 2.9.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests/requests-2.9.1.tar.gz#md5=0b7f480d19012ec52bab78292efd976d
Processing requests-2.9.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\panta\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-mbdcgv\requests-2.9.1\setup.cfg
Running requests-2.9.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\panta\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-mbdcgv\requests-2.9.1\egg-dist-tmp-rzrv6w
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

warning: easy_install: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
```

An it creates the folder C:\Users\panta\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-mbdcgv\requests-2.9.1 with a setup.py but when I try to run, it gives an error "No commands supplied".
So, there is a way to import requests on ironpython 2.7.5?

EDIT:Now with easy_install it "worked" but when i try to "import requests" i receive the following:

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg\requests\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 330, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 320, in exec_
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'
```

So, no requests module for ironpython?

Comment: Looks like the SSL layer is incompatible. `setup.py` takes commands, like `setup.py install`. However, `pip` is showing that `requests` is not going to work once installed; `pip` *uses* `requests`.

Comment: See https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2324; `six` being incompatible with IronPython seems to be the only thing.

Comment: you can try pythonnet if ironpython does not work, but it depends on your application

Comment: Now I'm using WebRequest from .net. It's working like a charm. Before using the webrequest I was using the urllib2, but when I used it too many times in a function I was having a stackoverflow exception for some reason ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075110/a-way-to-run-an-infinite-loop-without-the-stackoverflowexception-on-ironpython?noredirect=1#comment57873370_35075110 ), now with webrequest the stackoverflow exception not happens anymore.

Comment: it looks like you managed to install it, but in the last invocation (your EDIT) you forgot to provide -X:Frames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `six` library used by `urllib3` (in turn used by `requests`) is not compatible with IronPython. See [issue 135](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/issues/135/have-a-fallback-for-sys_getframe-usage-in) in the `six` project tracker, which may have a work-around.

Apparently, that's the *only* thing standing in the way of IronPython-compatibility, see [issue #2324](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2324) in the `requests` issue tracker.

You probably could make it work by replacing the definition for `exec_()` with calls directly to `exec()`, in the `six` module. `urllib3` doesn't actually use any calls to `six.exec_()` anyway, and `exec()` *works just fine* in Python 2 code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it works at least for trivial cases.

My exact install command is:

```
ipy.exe -X:Frames -m pip install --user requests
```

And the example session right after:

```
c:\cygwin64\home\rejap>ipy -X:Frames
IronPython 2.7.5 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.get('http://google.com')
C:\Users\rejap\AppData\Roaming\Python\IronPython27\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1: DeprecationWarning: object.__new__() takes no parameters
from __future__ import absolute_import
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>>
```